# How to declare local variable (Allen Bradley studio 5000)

Tags: plc

How to declare local variable in structured Text in Allen Bradley studio 5000. 
I have tried the following which did not work. mnemonic/syntax is not recognized?

```
VAR
   x: INT;
END_VAR
```

global variables do work as, **TEST_INPUT** and **TEST_INPUT_BOOL**  are globally declared.

```
IF TEST_INPUT.0 THEN
    TEST_INPUT_BOOL := 1;
ELSE
    TEST_INPUT_BOOL := 0;
END_IF;
```

Answer (score 6):

In Allen-Bradley RSLogix 5000 / Studio 5000, local tags (variables) are not declared inline in structured text routines.  Instead, tags are defined in the Tag Browser.  "Controller Tags" holds the controller-scoped (global) tags, and each Program has its own "Parameters and Local Tags" section where the program-scoped tags are defined.  Tags shown in the Local Tags section of a program can be used in any routine in that program.

Once you add your program-scoped tag to the appropriate Tag Browser, you can use the tag in your structured text routine.  If you try to use a tag that is not declared as either a program-scoped or controller-scoped tag, you will get a verify error.